# regex validation for multiple input formats from a single input

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, ip-address, ipv4

I have a situation where I should check for 2 different cases from one input. There is a validation function which validates for domain names and ipv4 and ipv6 address. Since I am accepting the subdomain names, the ipv4 address when fails to be a valid address is considered as a subdomain and the function is returning true which should not be doing that. so I need help to rewrite the code according to the input. If the input is of ipv4 or ipv6 format it should check the validation condition related to them otherwise it should check the conditions for the domain name.

```
validateDomain = (input) => {
    const domainRegex =
      /^(?=.{0,63}$)([A-Za-z0-9]+\s*([-_]\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.\s*[A-Za-z0-9]{2,6})*)?$/;
    const ipRegex =
      /^\b((?:(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})\b$/;
      // /^\b(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})\b$/;
    if (ipRegex.test(input)) {
      return true;
    } else if (domainRegex.test(input)) return true;
    return false;
  };
```

I tried to check for the IP address and then check for the domain but as soon as it is failing for the ip regex validation it is considered as the subdomain and returning true;

example:
123.123.255.256 must be a invalid ip address because the last part is greater than 255
as soon as this condition is failed it is being considered as domain which can consist the numbers and can also be a sub domain and returning true which should not be happening and return false

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but, the C# code `if (ipRegex.test(input)) { return true; } else if (domainRegex.test(input)) return true; return false;`  could be simplified to `return ipRegex.test(input) || domainRegex.test(input);` because the or (i.e. `||`) only evaluates the RHS if the LHS is false, this is referred to as "short circuit evaluation".

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be correct. The issue is with the regex expression that matches the domain names. I have made some changes to it and now you should be able to detect domains and subdomains better.

This is the altered regex expression for `domainRegex`

```
^(?=.{0,63}$)([A-Za-z0-9]+\s*([-_]\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.\s*[A-Za-z]{2,6})*)?$
```

Here is a short explanation of the expression:

- `^`: Start of the string.
- `(?=.{0,63}$)`: Positive lookahead assertion limiting the length of the entire string from 0 to 63 characters.
- `(`: Start of a capturing group.

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+`: Matches one or more alphanumeric characters.
  - `([-_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*`: Allows for hyphens or underscores followed by more alphanumeric characters, and this group can repeat zero or more times. This part matches subdomains separated by a hyphen or underscore.
  - `(\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})*`: Allows for a dot followed by two to six alphanumeric characters. This part represents the top-level domain (TLD), such as `.com`, `.org`, `.net`, etc.

  > This is where I have made the changes, your original expression matched all alphanumeric characters for the Top Level Domain. However, ICAAN does not have any numeric values in the TLD as of now. numbers are only allowed for puny code. It does not look like you are checking for that so removing the numbers from TLD matching should fix some of the issues.
  > Also there are a few TLDs longer than six characters, not sure why you are only looking for TLDs less than six characters long.
- `)?`: Closes the capturing group and makes the entire pattern optional, allowing an empty string or a valid domain name to match.

  > This is something I do not understand because, any kind of string is being matched here, whether or not it is a domain. Just any string without spaces gets matched because of this.
- `$`: End of the string.

Here is another expression to match domains and subdomains in case you are having issues with that expression

```
^(?=.{1,253}$)([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,63}$
```